# What is “:” in regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I am got a regular expression in sed, I am not sure ":" stand for anything here.

```
sed 's/:[^\t]*//g'
```

Could you please give me some infomation?

Update: I got the command from a publication, I'm confused because if the `:` is a normal character, then the `[^\t]` following it means the start of the line, which seems to actually match a `:` before the start of the line, which doesn't seem to have any effect?

Best.

Zhang.

Comment: Why is this tagged with python-re?

Comment: @user1934428, sorry, I have edit it.

Comment: It means match all occurances of `:` up to the next occurance of tab (non greedy) and remove them all `g`

Comment: If you go to https://regex101.com/ and plug in your regex it will explain everything to you

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused because if the : is a normal character, then the `[^\t]` following it means the start of the line, which seems to actually match a : before the start of the line, which doesn't seem to have any effect?

Normally, `^` means "start of line", that's right.

However, what you're looking at here [is a **character set**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). And in that context, the `^` means "negated".

So actually, `[^\t]` has got nothing at all do do with "start of line". It means "not a tab". (`\t` means "tab character".)

In summary, this regex:

```
:[^\t]*
```

means "a literal `:` character, followed by any number of non-tab characters".

Comment: Hi Lord，I got it, thanks for your kindly and careful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about `:` in regex. It simply matches a `:` character.

All special characters are [listed in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (that's Python since you tagged with `python-re`; the dialect used by `sed` is different but also doesn't have a special meaning for `:`).

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help, I got the command from a publication, I'm confused because if the `:` is a normal character, then the `[^\t]` following it means the start of the line, which seems to actually match a `:` before the start of the line, which doesn't seem to have any effect?

Comment: `[^\t]` does not mean start of line. Inside square brackets, the `^` means negation, so "anything that is not a tab"